# Origin of object not moving when armature moves the object

Tags: armature, unity

I have created a turret style gun in Blender for my first *Unity* game. I've created an object with a single face at the end of the gun barrel in order to attach a *Line Renderer* in *Unity*, but the line is shooting from above the barrel.

When I look in Blender, the origin of the single face is higher than the face itself. The reason is because I built the turret with its arm stood up straight and I have now used the armature to bend the arm into a shape similar to the less than symbol (<).

The turret is all one object and the single face is a child of that object. The single face follows the gun barrel perfectly when I move the armature, but the origin stays in its original position. If I enter edit mode the single face moves back to its origin. Even if I set origin to center of mass in object mode it still goes to the original position. If I apply the location of the face then the origin goes to 0,0,0 and the line renderer draws from the base of the turret.

How can I get the origin to move with the face/object so the line renderer draws from the correct position?

Comment: Armatures don't move the object's origin. That's just Blender.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to calculate the offset to make line render at the correct starting position? I.e. work out how much the bone has moved in relation to its original position? (Even though the default pose was positioned in blender)

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Sure. It's my first time making a 3D model so it's not the best :P Plus the normals were wrong on some faces when I baked the texture, so the colours are dark in places and need to be redone lol. Here's the link: [Turret Blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1948/)